# Why can Putty SSH by hostname but Mac OS X cannot?

Tags: ssh, dns, hostname

When I installed Putty on my Windows laptop I could SSH to my Linux server by using that computer's host name.  On my Mac, I had to use the IP address.  Any idea how Windows did name resolution when the Mac didn't?

When I did a SSH from the Linux box to the Mac, I had to do `name.local`, if that plays any part.

Answer (score 0):

If both hosts use the same DNS, you have something added to `hosts` file, and miss this on the Mac.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the Linux server is on your local network (and i'm guessing it is due to the name.local reference), you might need to change a few things in the Mac's network settings:

1. Go to Apple menu > System Preferences > Network
2. Highlight the connection you're using (Wi-Fi or Ethernet) and click 'Advanced...' in the lower right
3. Go to the DNS tab
4. Confirm that your DNS Servers and (if applicable) Search Domains options are set up correctly — maybe compare to Windows's IP settings
5. For a Linux server (and for just resolving DNS) this probably doesn't matter, but just in case, check the WINS tab as well. You generally want to be in the same work group as your other machines